# Proof that any linear operator in unitary space can be represented as $A=A_1+iA_2$ where A1 and A2 are Hermitian operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Need to find the proof of "Any linear operator in unitary space can be represented as $A=A_1+iA_2$ only one way, where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are Hermitian operators".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you mean are bounded linear operators in a Hilbert space.  For any $A$, you can take $A_1 = (A + A^*)/2$ and $A_2 = (A - A^*)/(2i)$ which are Hermitian.

EDIT: BTW, this is not true for closed densely-defined unbounded linear operators: there is no reason for the domains of $A$ and $A^*$ to coincide, or even to have anything but 0 in their intersection.